# Insert a datepicker in a jquery datatable

Tags: jquery, datepicker, datatables

I have a project datatable where I would like to insert a datepicker in a row.  I have this, but it only displays the input not the datepicker:

```
"render": function(data, type, full, meta){
                    var $tb = $("<input type='text' class='inlineevaldate' style='width:50px;'></input>");
                    $tb.attr("id", "etxt" + full[0]);
                    $("#etxt" + full[0]).val(full[12]);
                    return $tb.prop("outerHTML");
                }
```

I can update the date with this:

```
initComplete : function(settings, json){
            $(".inlineevaldate").datepicker({
                changeMonth: true,
                changeYear: true,
                modal: false,
                autoClose: true,
                onSelect: function () {
                    $("#btnUpdateProject").focus();
                    var whichrow = $(this);
                    var id = whichrow[0].id;
                    var val = whichrow[0].value;
                    var projectid = whichrow[0].id.substring(4);
                    $.ajax({
                        type: 'POST',
                        data: { projectid : projectid, date : val },
                        url: '@Url.Action("SetProjectEvalDate")',
                        success: function(data){
                            if (data === "ERROR") {
                                ErrorDialog("#MessageDialog", "#lblError", "The was an error encountered, please try again later.", "Error");
                                return false;
                            }
                        }
                    });
                }
            });
```

But I cannot set the initial value of the input.  Any Ideas?

Comment: `textbox` not `textarea`?

Comment: @bassxzero yes just a textbox, like I normally do when creating a date picker.

Comment: You'll likely need to call `$('.datepicker').datepicker();` in a callback...? Perhaps work up a JSFiddle with what you're trying...?

Comment: No such html element `<textbox>` ... usually assign datepicker to an `<input>`

Comment: @charlietfl Yeah, I noticed that after I posted.  However, I get a similar result - the input shows but it does not display a datepicker when clicked.

Comment: You are returning the html string...which means you lose all event listeners. Consider initializing datepickers after all rows rendered using a class

Comment: @charlietfl do you have suggestions on how to do that?

Comment: OK, so I added the initialization of the datepickers like this:

 initComplete : function(settings, json){
                $(".inlinedate").datepicker({
                    changeMonth: true,
                    changeYear: true,
                    modal: false,
                    autoClose: true,
                    onSelect: function () {
                        $("#btnUpdateProject").focus(); 
                    }
                });
            },
But then how do I know which row I am in??

Comment: I can update the date with this:

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I render the column with this:

```
"render": function(data, type, full, meta){
                    var $tb = $("<input type='text' class='inlineevaldate' value='" + full[12] + "' style='width:50px;'></input>");
                    $tb.attr("id", "etxt" + full[0]);
                    return $tb.prop("outerHTML");
                }
```

And then configure the datepicker after the tables is initialized:

```
initComplete : function(settings, json){
            $(".inlineevaldate").datepicker({
                changeMonth: true,
                changeYear: true,
                modal: false,
                autoClose: true,
                onSelect: function () {
                    $("#btnUpdateProject").focus();
                    var whichrow = $(this);
                    var id = whichrow[0].id;
                    var val = whichrow[0].value;
                    var projectid = whichrow[0].id.substring(4);
                    $.ajax({
                        type: 'POST',
                        data: { projectid : projectid, date : val },
                        url: '@Url.Action("SetProjectEvalDate")',
                        success: function(data){
                            if (data === "ERROR") {
                                ErrorDialog("#MessageDialog", "#lblError", "The was an error encountered, please try again later.", "Error");
                                return false;
                            }
                        }
                    });
                }
            });
```

Comment: Thanks a lot...that helped me..!